# Некорректная работа обработчика событий до/после обновления страницы ajax-ом

Tags: jquery, ajax

Как правильно обработчик повесить? [Пример кода](https://jsfiddle.net/2aqcbyno/)

```
<table>
<tr id='cart_item_row_23'>
  <td>
    <div class='cart_del' title='Удалить товар из корзины' data-cart-item-par-id='23'>  <span>1</span></div></td>
                                    </tr></table>

$(document).on('click', '.cart_del',function(event){
        var target = $(event.target);
        var par_id = target.attr('data-cart-item-par-id');
        alert(par_id);

    });
```

Если обработчик указывать так, как в примере, то код начинает работать только после обновления содержимого ajax-ом, а при обновлении страницы работать перестаёт.

Если повесить обработчик так: `$('.cart_del').click(function(){...`, то всё наоборот - после обновления контента ajax-ом обработчик слетает, а после обновления страницы снова работают. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: где находится `$(document).on('click', ...`?

Comment: Igor хотел узнать, находится ли это внутри `$(document).ready()` или где-то еще, или само по себе висит?

Comment: с местными товарищами иногда страшно иметь дело

Comment: а что именно обновляется аяксом?

Comment: В `$(document).ready()` обёрнуто

Comment: обновляется содержимое корзины, включая `.cart_del`

Comment: Без `$(document).ready()` всё ровно то же

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2aqcbyno/1/ - click работает как для существующего, так и для динамически созданных элементов

Comment: @Igor в как это можно сделать неправильно? Через консоль проверял - приходит всё содержимое корзины с добавленным товаром, вставляется корректно. Слетали обработчики, после вставки нового содержимого, а теперь они только начинают работать после обновления содержимого

Comment: @Torawhite - jsfiddle работает?

Comment: @Igor да, работает.

Comment: @Torawhite - Давайте разбираться, чем Ваш маркап и код отличается от фидла.

Comment: @Igor но у меня не цепляется обработчик, при обычной загрузке страницы, до работы с ajax. Это же странно...

Comment: @Igor отличается html - таблица обёрнута ещё кучей тегов и лежит в выпадающем списке

Comment: @Igor проще [ссылку](http://store.torawhite.ru/) дать - корзина

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.cart_del',`  - не обернут в `$(document).ready`

Comment: @Igor это я его убрал, попробовать, изменится что-то или нет ничего не поменялось  до этого было обёрнуто

Comment: @Igor вернул обратно